# How to assign multiple values to property "com.liferay.portlet.display-category" in DXP for OOTB portlets?

Tags: portlet, liferay-7, liferay-dxp

I am trying to update the display category of Out of the box portlets like Blogs, Asset Publisher etc.
As per OSGI configuration way of modifying it in DXP, I have created a configuration file in "`osgi/config`" folder with name like "`com.liferay.blogs.web.internal.portlet.BlogsPortlet.cfg`"

If I specify single value like `com.liferay.portlet.display-category=category.sample`

It works fine and shows portlet in the sample category.

However, I would like to set multiple values. I have tried below combinations.

1)

```
com.liferay.portlet.display-category=category.collaboration
com.liferay.portlet.display-category=category.sample
```

2)

```
com.liferay.portlet.display-category=["category.collaboration","category.sample"]
```

3)

```
com.liferay.portlet.display-category=\\,
category.collaboration,\
category.sample
```

However, none of them worked for multiple values.

I have referred this [here](https://dev.liferay.com/ca/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/7-0/understanding-system-configuration-files)

Any help on this is appreciated.

Regards,
Suyash Bhalekar

Answer (score 1):

I could manage to achieve this by changing the extension of file from ".cfg" to ".config" and it worked like charm. i.e I renamed the it to **"com.liferay.blogs.web.internal.portlet.BlogsPortlet.config"** and then added
**com.liferay.portlet.display-category=["category.collaboration","category.sample"]**